# Agrupar tags separado por vírgula PHP

Tags: php

Bom dia!

Seguinte tô com uma dúvida, e não tô conseguindo chegar conclusão.

Tô criando um campo chamado tag onde serve para buscar os posts relacionados com tag.

No banco ela é preenchido da seguinte forma;

```
post1 tag: exemplo1,exemplo2
post2 tag: exemplo3,exemplo2
```

E como deve ser saída:

```
tag: exemplo1,exemplo2,exemplo3
```

Se reparar bem, ela está separado por vírgula. Logo faço um explode para separar string. Até aí tudo bem.

A minha dúvida é na parte de string repetindo iguais.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT tag FROM posts WHERE tag NOT IN('') ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
  $explode = explode(',',$row['tag']);
  $count = count($explode);
  for($i = 0; $i < $count-1; $i++){
    echo $explode[$i];
  }
}
```

Com esse código ela tá saindo da seguinte forma:

```
tag: exemplo1,exemplo2,exemplo3,exemplo2
```

Qual maneira de agrupar string repetidas?

Comment: sua ideia é "agrupar" tags repetidas ou remover?

Comment: Remover, desculpa pelo erro de explicação.

Comment: podes fazer a seguinte lógica:  implode > array_unique > explode

Comment: Não leve a mal. Porém, acredito que o ideal seria alterar totalmente o sistema de banco de dados, pelo código mostrado aparentemente está salvando várias informações em uma única coluna, divididas por virgula, [podendo ser considerado uma violação ao 1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), [veja este exemplo no SO de um sistema de tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160307/how-can-i-create-a-tagging-system-using-php-and-mysql) ou [esta que fala de maneira genérica de relação n:n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533260/nn-relation-mysql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não manjo de "mysqli" más sabendo que seu retorno traz todas as tags agrupadas podes fazer algo como:

```
$raw = 'exemplo1,exemplo2,exemplo3,exemplo2';
$string = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $raw)));
echo $string; // output: exemplo1,exemplo2,exemplo3
```

Fiz algo parecido a algum tempo fica de referencia se te ajudar: [selecting-hashtag-into-database-from-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717470/selecting-hashtag-into-database-from-url/26292376#26292376)

Comment: Agradeço! Com a sua ajuda resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Para quem quiser o código.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT tag FROM posts WHERE tag NOT IN ('')");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $explode = explode(',',$row['tag']);
    $count = count($explode);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $array .= $explode[$i].',';
    }
}

echo implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $array)));
```